# Qualtrics: How to access embedded data in javascript

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I have made a survey in Qualtrics, and I want to present a chart to respondents based on their answers. I have stored four weights in Embedded data. Yet, how do I call or access these embedded data in javascript? In the code below I want to replace the values 10, 20, 30, 40 with weights that are stored in embedded data.

I have found this on the internet, but I am not sure what to do with it.

*How to access and write values to an embedded data field at any point in the survey
To access embedded data at any time using javascript: simply set a variable to be equal to the piped text required to access to embedded data in survey questions (as a string).
For example,
var myData = "${e://Field/myEmbeddedData}" (don't forget the quotes!)*

But do I have to put this piece of code in the code below or somewhere else? I have tried to do this, and then replace e.g. 10 with {MyData}, but it did not work. Did I do something wrong?

Thank you in advance!

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Characteristic', 'Weight', { role: 'style' } ],
    ['one', 10, 'color: #394165'],
    ['two', 20, 'color: #0CA5AA'],
    ['three', 30, 'color: #F2941A'],
    ['four', 40, 'color: #E64E67']
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
                   { calc: function(dt, rowIndex) { return dt.getValue(rowIndex, 1).toString() + '%' },
                     sourceColumn: 1,
                     type: "string",
                     role: "annotation" },
                   2]);

  var options = {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    title: 'Chart',
    vAxis:  { format: '#\'%\'', maxValue: '100', minValue: '0'},
    legend: { position: 'none'},
    bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
          };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Characteristic', 'Weight', { role: 'style' } ],
    ['one', parseInt("${e://Field/ed1}"), 'color: #394165'],
    ['two', parseInt("${e://Field/ed2}"), 'color: #0CA5AA'],
    ['three', parseInt("${e://Field/ed3}"), 'color: #F2941A'],
    ['four', parseInt("${e://Field/ed4}"), 'color: #E64E67']
  ]);
```

Where ed1, ed2, ed3, and ed4 are your embedded data fields.